# Menu showing behind textboxes, labels. ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a web page with the main menu on the top. Then on individual pages, I have a table with some textboxes, etc in the table. When I mouse hover above the menu to get the drop down, it hides behind my textboxes, etc. Now it does this on some pages and not on others, and each page is basically contructed the same way. So I'm kind of lost.

Help?

**Here is a pic of whats going on:**

[image]

Comment: How is the menu being generated?  Javascript? ASP.NET Menu Control?

Comment: ASP.NET Navigation menu control on my master page. Some pages it does this and some it doesn't.

Comment: Dan's probably got it right.  You need to use a bit of CSS to set the z-index on the menu so that it's always on top.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my css file and set the z-index. Fixed.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you like one of the answers below, you can mark it as the correct answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.  You earn 2 rep by doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the z-index of menu drop down div to 9999:

```
#menuDropDown {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're talking about CSS z-index

have a read of [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp) on the subject

Answer (score 0):

I take a look on my example

[Bring element to front/back](http://jsfiddle.net/EqUxz/)